# Transfer selected rows from one GridView to another GridView in webform (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Gridview controls. In the first one I bound the data from a stored procedure using SQL, and I want to export selected rows from Gridview1 to GridView2.

This is my code for binding the data of Gridview1:

```
// Load the data of [Student_Registration] store procedured
// from SQL to gridview1
sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlcom.CommandText = "Student_Registration";
sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@SSID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(LblSubjectStudyId.Text.Trim());
sqlcom.Connection = con;
try
{
    con.Open();
    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
    GridView1.DataSource = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where in this code do you try to transfer the selected row from grid1 to grid2? Where/when do you want to do that at all?

Comment: Please share some code of what have you tried so far to achieve your goal. Please understand that SO is not a free code service. Try something and post the code then someone may be able to help you out.

Comment: i wrote this code in Page_Load in my web form.and it work true and bind the data to my Gridview1.now i want to selected the row in gridview1 by checkbox and transfer it to gridview2

Comment: after that transfer, delet the transferd row in gridview1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, first of all you need to add a check box control in item Template and then you will have to put an export button on page.

At a button click, find all the selected rows in the grid view by using value of the checked items and then convert the whole row into a data row and add it to a table.

Now bind this datatable to the gridview source.

Comment: Thx so much for your advice

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Hi Dear. I have another question. According to what you said i want to pour of my grid into a data table. and then I want to get the values of the selection rows in to another grid.